# How to declare HTMLElement variable outside of a function in Angular component.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to declare HTMLElement variables visible to all functions in given class, however i am unable to do so for some reason. Method of declaring it before constructor and then assigning its value in constructor does not work, but when i declare and assign it in a function, for example employeesClick() it works.

I am trying to avoid using multiple instances of same code, as i need to change other buttons based on which one was clicked.

There are no errors, but nothing happens. How do i do this?

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  projects:HTMLElement;
  constructor() { 
    this.projects=document.getElementById('projects');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  projectsClick(){
    this.projects.style.color="#DEA731";
  }
  employeesClick(){
    var employees : HTMLElement = document.getElementById('employees');
    employees.style.color="#DEA731";
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it would work if you move the code from the constructor into `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@ViewChild` directive. Just create a reference for a button and get an element in your `.ts` file.

For example, html looks like:

```html
<button #btn> ... </button>
```

In your `.ts`:

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('btn') buttonRef: ElementRef;

...
someMethod(){
  //do something like change a text color of your button
  this.buttonRef.nativeElement.style.color = "#aaa";
}
```

The `buttonRef` is a global variable in the class and you can use it where you need.
Don't forget to import `ViewChild` and `ElementRef` from `@angular/core`;